# Role based login with spring webflow

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml, spring-webflow

I have a login page and according to the user, I need to select with two different webflows. I am using spring webflow, JSF2 and hibernate. Can i use subflow for the purpose? Or By using spring authentication is it possible to switch flows?

Comment: the question is too vague.. did you even look up in google? what did you try? you could use spring security, or develop your own filter to handle authentication/authorization

Comment: well i m using spring web flow. and it has two flows like admin and manager, i need to choose between this two flows as per the responsibility of the user. By googling i got a hint that i could use sub flows.. But i coud'nt find the exact way to achieve it.

Comment: authentication has nothing to do with flows. first take care of authentication, using spring-security, or a custom filter as mentioned earlier. once you have authentication implemented, you can redirect to a different url (flow) depending on user role